Why its reported "proto: cannot parse invalid wire-format data" when using protobuf in golang to unmarshal pb message?
There are two pb struct in my message.pb.go, the file is generate by messsage.proto.
The message.proto is like:
syntax = "proto2";
option go_package = "../record_proto";
package record_proto;

message A {
  optional string name = 1;
  optional uint64 id = 2;
  optional string sex = 3;
  message mail_attachment{
    required string attach_md5 = 1;
    required string mime_type = 2;
    required string name = 3;
  }
  repeated mail_attachment attachment = 4;
}

message A_send_version {
  optional string name = 1;
  optional uint64 id = 2;
  message mail_attachment{
    required string attach_md5 = 1;
    required string mime_type = 2;
    required string name = 3;
  }
  repeated mail_attachment attachment = 4;
}

For some reson, in the program I need to use message A to receive the pb message and the use message A_send_version send the pb message to another platform.
In  message.pb.go they like below, all var are pointers.
type A struct {
   Name *string
   Id   *uint64
   ...
   Mail_Attachment *A_mail_attachment
}

In the code, I restruct the struct like this:
func restructPb(log pb.A) *pb.A_send_version {
    newLog := new(pb.A_send_version)
    newLog.name = log.GetName()
    newLog.Id = log.GetId()
    ...
    return newLog
}

Finally, marshal them and send it by kafka producer.
Here come to the problem, when unmarshalling the messages, I get error proto: cannot parse invalid wire-format data.
I tried to find out. I get the base64 encoding marshaled pb message, And write a demo to decode then umarshal it. I really can't decode it.
func main() {
    target :=  new(pb.A_send_version)

    decodeBytes, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(origin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(decodeBytes))
    err = proto.Unmarshal(decodeBytes, target)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(target)
}

At last I also tried to print in log before the struct to be marshalled, the error disappeared , as the same time I decode it use the same demo, they all can be unmarshalled.
But when I remove the log.Print, the error appears again.
It's really weired.

Hey, does the error appear on decoding or unmarshaling? And, what's origin in your example?

The only error I can see is "proto: cannot parse invalid wire-format data", and nothing else ......

That didn't really answer my questions, though.

Sorry, the origin is the  message serialized by protobuf encoded with base64

It's... unusual... that you'd need 2 Messages when the only difference between them is an optional field.
The Message name A_send_version also does not follow the Style Guide for Message and Field names.
Using protoc (27.0), the Golang generates structs called e.g. ASendVersion not A_send_version so I'm unsure how you're generating the stubs.
Are you trying to support an API that sends Protobuf messages over HTTP/REST?
protoc \
--go_out=${PWD} \
message.proto

The following sample works for me:
module github.com/foo/stackoverflow/78562915

go 1.22.0

require google.golang.org/protobuf v1.34.1


package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    pb "github.com/foo/stackoverflow/78562915/record_proto"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

func ptr[T string | uint64](val T) *T {
    return &val
}
func main() {
    a := &pb.A{
        Name: ptr("name"),
        Id:   ptr(uint64(1)),
        Sex:  ptr("sex"),
        Attachment: []*pb.AMailAttachment{
            {
                AttachMd5: ptr("attach_md5"),
                MimeType:  ptr("mime_type"),
                Name:      ptr("name"),
            },
        },
    }
    b, err := proto.Marshal(a)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    origin := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b)
    target := new(pb.ASendVersion)

    decodeBytes, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(origin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(decodeBytes))
    err = proto.Unmarshal(decodeBytes, target)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    j, err := protojson.Marshal(target)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(j))
}


Yields:
{
  "name":"name",
  "id":"1",
  "attachment":[{
    "attachMd5":"attach_md5",
    "mimeType":"mime_type",
    "name":"name"
  }]
}


I have to apologize that the pb struct is just a example, my company do not allow me to show these, the true pb in our development is follow the Style Guide.

The reason why use different pb to send one same message, it's unknown, this is desgined by someone who has resigned. And it's hard to change now. Although this seems unreasonable
